# Browser gets stuck on 302 "Object Moved" page

Tags: asp.net, http, browser

I'm getting reports of sporadic instances where users in various browsers get a 302 page, but instead of automatically redirecting, the browser just displays the `Object moved to here` HTML sent by the browser. What could possibly cause this? If it were one browser on one machine, I'd blame a bad installation or something, but I've had a handful of reports, just in the past couple of days, from a number of machines and browsers, so I'm nervous that something is actually wrong with the HTTP Response, even though it couldn't be *that* wrong or the app wouldn't work almost everywhere else, as it does.

Anyway, here's the Response packet:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /nextpage
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: cookiename={...data...}; path=/
Date: Fri, 10 Oct 2014 14:31:44 GMT
Content-Length: 124

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/nextpage">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: [This post](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/31274) maybe helpful given "sporadic". Hth...

Comment: This was very helpful, but from the article, it sounds like a UserAgent either does or doesn't do the right thing with a relative url. The browsers where this is failing do still work most of the time. What could account for only sporadic failures on a single machine?